# ¿Cómo crear un grafico de barras combinado con 2 ejes Y en R o excel?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot

[image: busco realizar un gráfico similar al de la imagen con R o excel.]
busco realizar grafico similar al de la imagen con R o excel. ayuda con la función y librería necesaria

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.